# How to use System.import() correctly?

Tags: node.js, jspm, systemjs

I use the `jspm` in my project.

But I need the server side nodejs file to execute some instruction.

For example, I need to use the `lodash` and found the guide in the https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

```
var System = require('jspm').Loader();
System.import('lodash').then(function (_) {  console.log(_); });
```

However, I want to use the lodash globally.
Just like

```
var _ = System.import('lodash');
var myArr = _.map([1, 2, 3], function(n) { return n * 3; });
```

It will show

> TypeError: _.map is not a function
>       at Object. (/Users/joyfeel/javascript/jspm-test/index.js:49:16)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
>       at normalLoader (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
>       at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel/lib/_babel-node.js:144:25)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)

Why does the `lodash` only be used in `.then` scope?

Could anyone tell me how to figure it out? Suppose we want to `System.import` other modules and use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_` can only be accessed in the scope of `then` because `System.import` always returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).
Therefore you have to wait for the Promise to be resolved before you can access its result.
Anyway i would not recommend you to use lodash globally.

But when you really want to use `_` globally you can do something like:

```
System.import('lodash').then(function(_) {
    GLOBAL._ = _;
});
```

Still you have to make sure that all code that uses GLOBAL._ waits till the Promise from the lodash import is resolved.
But again: i would discourage you doing it that way but recommend that you import lodash in every module that needs it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!  :)